# ¿Cómo puedo insertar registros a una tabla con un cursor, ordenados por un campo específico, y no en el orden de inserción?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cursores, mysql-procedimiento

Tengo 2 tablas:

**admins**

```
+-----------+
| dni       |
+-----------+
| 12345678A |
| X8343242B |
+-----------+

+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dni   | varchar(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**entradas_salidas**

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | dni       | entrada             | salida              |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 94 | 12345678A | 2022-04-28 07:11:05 | 2022-04-28 15:24:27 |
| 95 | X8343242B | 2022-04-28 06:55:58 | 2022-04-28 15:13:50 |
| 96 | 12345678A | 2022-04-28 06:59:32 | 2022-04-28 15:11:31 |
| 97 | X8343242B | 2022-04-28 06:58:17 | 2022-04-28 15:09:30 |
| 98 | 12345678A | 2022-04-28 07:04:24 | 2022-04-28 15:06:18 |
| 99 | X8343242B | 2022-04-28 06:58:55 | 2022-04-28 15:13:56 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+

+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------------------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default                               | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------------------------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                                  | auto_increment |
| dni     | varchar(9)  | YES  | MUL | NULL                                  |                |
| entrada | varchar(19) | YES  |     | cast(current_timestamp() as datetime) |                |
| salida  | varchar(19) | YES  |     | NULL                                  |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------------------------+----------------+
```

He creado un procedimiento que inserta un registro en la tabla **entradas_salidas** por cada registro de la tabla **admins**, con una hora de entrada y de salida aleatorias (dentro de unos límites).

En la tabla **entradas_salidas** se ve que el orden de los registros está determinado por el orden de los registros de la tabla **admins**. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que los registros estén ordenados por el campo **entrada** en vez de por los dni.

La tabla debería quedar así:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | dni       | entrada             | salida              |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 94 | X8343242B | 2022-04-28 06:55:58 | 2022-04-28 15:13:50 |
| 95 | X8343242B | 2022-04-28 06:58:17 | 2022-04-28 15:09:30 |
| 96 | X8343242B | 2022-04-28 06:58:55 | 2022-04-28 15:13:56 |
| 97 | 12345678A | 2022-04-28 06:59:32 | 2022-04-28 15:11:31 |
| 98 | 12345678A | 2022-04-28 07:04:24 | 2022-04-28 15:06:18 |
| 99 | 12345678A | 2022-04-28 07:11:05 | 2022-04-28 15:24:27 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

(Ya se que al hacer un select puedo poner **ORDER BY** pero me interesa que el campo **id** también esté ordenado)

**Procedimiento que he hecho:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fichaje_admins;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `fichaje_admins`()
BEGIN
DECLARE fecha VARCHAR(19) DEFAULT TIMESTAMP(NOW());
DECLARE hora VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE minuto VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE segundo VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE hora_entrada VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE hora_salida VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE dnis VARCHAR(9);
DECLARE curAdmins CURSOR FOR SELECT dni FROM admins;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    IF DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) != 7 OR DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) != 1 THEN
        OPEN curAdmins;
        loopAdmins: LOOP
            SET fecha = TIMESTAMP(NOW());
            SET fecha = SUBSTRING_INDEX(fecha, " ", 1);
            SET hora = FLOOR(RAND()*(7-6+1)+6);
            IF hora = 7 THEN
                SET minuto = FLOOR(RAND()*(12-0+1)+1);
            ELSE
                SET minuto = FLOOR(RAND()*(59-48+1)+48);
            END IF;
            SET segundo = FLOOR(RAND()*(59-0+1)+1);
            SET hora_entrada = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CONCAT("0",hora), -2), ":", SUBSTRING(CONCAT("0",minuto), -2), ":", SUBSTRING(CONCAT("0",segundo), -2));
            IF hora = 7 THEN
                SET minuto = minuto + FLOOR(RAND()*(12-0+1)+1);
            ELSE
                SET minuto = FLOOR(RAND()*(12-0+1)+1);
            END IF;
            SET segundo = FLOOR(RAND()*(59-0+1)+1);
            SET hora_salida = CONCAT("15:", SUBSTRING(CONCAT("0",minuto), -2), ":", SUBSTRING(CONCAT("0",segundo), -2));
            FETCH curAdmins INTO dnis;
            IF finished = 1 THEN
                LEAVE loopAdmins;
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO entradas_salidas (dni, entrada, salida) VALUES (dnis, CONCAT(fecha, " ", hora_entrada), CONCAT(fecha, " ", hora_salida));
        END LOOP loopAdmins;
        CLOSE curAdmins;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: has probado en lugar de hacer un cursor un ``INSERT INTO Tabla SELECT datos1,datos2 FROM tabla;`` te puede resultar muchos mas comodo

Comment: Pues efectivamente, lo he resuelto con ```INSERT INTO entradas_salidas (dni,entrada,salida) SELECT dni, fecha_entrada as entrada, fecha_salida) FROM admins ORDER BY entrada;``` Muchas gracias.

Comment: te he añadido la respuesta para que se soluciones@MrJant

Comment: Esto.. no es cierto... Ninguna base de datos asegura el orden de una tabla a menos que se haga una seleccion con un order by. Esto puede funcionar por un rato, pero la base de datos puede decidir mover los datos a otro lado, y el select va a dejar de estar ordenado. Aca hay un error conceptual terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso se puede hacer simplemente con un `INSERT INTO table SELECT...`

**Seria algo parecido a esto :**

```
INSERT INTO Tabla SELECT datos1,datos2 FROM tabla;
```

**En tu caso :**

```
INSERT INTO entradas_salidas (dni,entrada,salida) SELECT dni, fecha_entrada as entrada, fecha_salida) FROM admins ORDER BY entrada;
```

Comment: Nota importante.. esto va a guardar estos datos de una forma que parece ordenada (y puede que la db hasta lo guarde ordenado) pero ninguna base de datos asegura un orden a menos que se use una clausula order by al mostrarlos.

Comment: Cierto, en mi caso sólo me interesaba que el orden de los id concordara con el orden de las fechas de entrada así que no es relevante para mí, pero es algo importante a tener en cuenta en otras situaciones.